# installing kbox3 - undefined symbol: dlopen

Tags: android, dlopen, busybox

I have tried installing kbox3 ("a port of Busybox and a number of other Linux utilities") using the [KBOX3 installation instructions](http://www.kevinboone.net/kbox3_install.html) on my Samsung Galaxy Tab S. Though, when I get to instruction no. 7 at which the shell gets tested I get the following:

```
$ ./kbox3/bin/kbox_shell
fakechroot: dlopen: undefined symbol: dlopen
```

What can I do?

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: Same thing happens on Samsung Note 10.1 2014 ed (unrooted).

Answer (score 3):

After installing KBOX3 copy manually an updated SO for Android 5:

```
wget http://www.kevinboone.net/libfakechroot_fix_dlopen_1.so
```

Copy this to /sdcard/Download via USB cable.
Then start the terminal emulator:

```
cd /sdcard/Download
cat libfakechroot_fix_dlopen_1.so > \
 /data/data/jackpal.androidterm/kbox3/lib/libfakechroot.so
```

See http://elinux.org/KBOX_Linux_emulator_for_Android

Comment: It worked, thanks.

Though I used Dropbox instead of a cable and (after having clicked at the file in the Dropbox folder in My Files) used

'cd /mnt/sdcard/Android/data/com.dropbox.android/files/scratch/
mv libfakechroot_fix_dlopen_1.so /data/data/jackpal.androidterm/kbox3/lib/libfakechroot.so'

after having renamed the original libfakechroot.so also using 'mv'.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer at http://kevinboone.net/kbox3_diary.html under 30th June.

Assuming you use Jack Palevich's Android Terminal Emulator download the patched [libfakechroot.so](http://kevinboone.net/libfakechroot_fix_dlopen_1.so) http://kevinboone.net/libfakechroot_fix_dlopen_1.so

And do:

```
cd /data/data/jackal.androidterm/kbox3/lib
cat libfakechroot.so > libfakechroot.so.orig
chmod 755 libfakechroot.so.orig
cat /sdcard/Download/libfakechroot_fix_dlopen_1.so > libfakechroot.so
```

After this it should work.

Comment: Thanks, I used a combination of yours and Geertivp's instructions.